# Grouping ExtJS radio buttons with different names to save in database

Tags: javascript, extjs, radio-button, radio-group, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to group radio buttons in ExtJS without using the same `name` config. Is this possible? This is my code:

```
 items:
    [
        {
            xtype: 'radio',
            name: 'is_self_employed',
            boxLabel: 'Self Employed:'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'radio',
            name: 'is_voluntary',
            boxLabel: 'Voluntary:'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'radio',
            name: 'is_ofw',
            boxLabel: 'OFW:'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'radio',
            name: 'is_non_working_spouse',
            boxLabel: 'Non Working Spouse:'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'radio',
            name: 'is_farmer_or_fisherman',
            boxLabel: 'Farmer or Fisherman:'
        }

    ]
```

Comment: The names must be the same if you want them to act as a group. Use the `inputValue` to specify the value.

Answer (score 1):

you want radio buttons with different names?

Radio buttons are grouped by their name and that will break their functionality, unless you do some JS Code to fix what you broke.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to set the same name to all radios and set different inputValue for each.

Another possible way of implementation would be to trigger uncheck of other radio buttons manually while enabling one.

```
 listeners: {
     change: function(rd, value) {
        if (value) {
          var radios = rd.up("form").query("radio");
          Ext.each(radios, function(r) {
            if (r != rd)
              r.setValue(false);
          });
        }
     }
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/s48FD/51/